# Bash scanning for filenames containing keywords and move them

Tags: bash

I'm looking to find a way to constantly scan a folder tree for new subfolders containing MKV/MP4 files. If that file contains a keyword and ends in MP4 or MKV, it'll be moved to a defined location matching that keyword. As a bonus, it would delete the folder and all it's leftover contents where the file resided previosly. The idea would be to have this run in the background and sort everything where it belongs and clean up after itself if possible.

example:

```
Media\anime\Timmy\Timmy_S1E1\Timmy_S1E1_720p.mkv    #Found Keyword Timmy, allowed filetype
```

Move to destination:

```
Media\series\Timmy\
```

Delete subfolder:

```
Media\anime\Timmy\Timmy_S1E1\
```

I would either do separate scripts for each keyword, or, if possible, have the script match each keyword with a destination

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/sh
#!/etc/shells/bin/bash

while true
do
    shopt -s globstar
    start_dir="//srv/MEDIA2/shows"                    
    for name in "$start_dir"/**/*.*; do   
        # search the directory recursively
    done
    sleep 300
done
```

Comment: ` If that file contains a keyword and ends in MP4 or MKV` If the file contains a keyword or the file __name__ contains the keyword?

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done by:

- creating a script that does what you want to do, once.
- run the script from cron, at a certain interval.  Say a couple minutes, or a couple hours, depends on the volume of files you receive.
- no need for a continually running daemon.

Ex:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_dir="/start/directory"
if [[ ! -d "$start_dir" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: start_dir ($start_dir) not found."
    exit 1
fi

target_dir="/target/directory"
if [[ ! -d "$target_dir" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: target_dir ($target_dir) not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Move all MP4 and MKV files to the target directory
find "$start_dir" -type f \( -name "*keyword*.MP4" -o -name "*keyword*.MKV" \) -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' file
do
    # add any processing here...
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    echo "Moving $filename to $target_dir..."
    mv "$file" "$target_dir/$filename"
done

# That being done, all that is left in start_dir can be deleted
find "$start_dir" -type d ! -path "$start_dir" -exec /bin/rm -fr {} \;
```

Details:

- scanning for files is most efficient with the `find` command
- the `-print0` with `read ...` method is to ensure all valid filenames are processed, even if they include spaces or other "weird" characters.
- the result of the above code is that each file that matches your keyword, with extensions MP4 or MKV will be processed once.
- you can then use `"$file"` to access the file being processed in the current loop.
- make sure you **ALWAYS** double quote `$file`, otherwise any weird filename will brake your code.  Well you should always double quote your variables anyway.
- more complex logic can be added for your specific needs.  Ex. create the target directory if it does not exist.  Create a different target directory depending on your keyword. etc.
- to delete all sub-directories under `$start_dir`, I use `find`.  Again this will process weird directory names.

---

One point, some will argue that it could all be done in 1 `find` command with `-exec` option.  True, but IMHO the version with the `while` loop is easier to code, understand, debug, learn.

And this construct is good to have in your bash toolbox.

---

When you create a script, only one `#!` line is needed.
And I fixed the indentation in your question, much easier to read your code properly indented and formatted (see the edit help in the question editor).

---

Last point to discuss, lets say you have a LARGE number of directories and files to process, and it is possible that new files are added while the script is running.  Ex. you are moving many MP4 files, and while it is doing it, new files are deposited in the directories.  Then when you do the deletion you *could* potentially loose files.

If such a case is possible, you could add a check for new files just before you do the `/bin/rm`, it would help.  To be absolutely certain, you could setup a script that processes 1 file, and have it triggered by `inotify`.  But that is another ball game, more complicated and out of scope for this answer.

Comment: You can actually get `find` to do your deletes natively without an exec rm -f.  
Check out the `-empty` and `-delete` arguments in the manual.
Eg, you can do stuff like `find <some dir> -type d -mtime +21 -empty -delete` and it will delete empty dirs which haven't been touched in 21 days

Comment: Indeed, great addition.